# Best website for Programming Language Icons

Tags: icons

I was wondering to find icon packs for all programming language icons. Can anyone suggest which one is good website where I can find all icons (Either official or based on some similar theme) related to any programming language.

Comment: Nice set of icons but the problem is same. It doesn't solve my problem. For example Spring, Hibernate etc.

Comment: Search on google image or on any other search engine

Comment: a very reliable source would be the open source addons for various IDEs, like https://github.com/PKief/vscode-material-icon-theme, https://github.com/vscode-icons/vscode-icons, https://github.com/file-icons/atom or https://github.com/mallowigi/a-file-icon-idea. These might be helpful as well https://github.com/devicons/devicon, https://github.com/Templarian/MaterialDesign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com) for all types of icons.

There are various websites another is [Flaticon](https://www.flaticon.com)

Comment: [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/) and [Flaticon](https://www.flaticon.com/) are nice websites which provide awesome icons but as I mentioned I am looking for icons related to programming languages. Unfortunately these sites don't include icons related to all programming languages. For example: I tried searching for Spring and Maven but couldn't find anything.

Comment: They do not include all of the programming languages icons yet some. you should include in your question which one are you looking for

Comment: I just started posting in here. Will keep in mind from next time onwards about detailed description. I am looking for icons related to Java, Spring, Hibernate, AWS, Spring Boot, Microservices, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, JQuery, Angular, Oracle, MySQL, JSF, Primefaces, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well after lots of surfing I found a good webpage for programming language icons.
[Programming Language Icons](https://www.pngguru.com/free-transparent-background-png-clipart-rdpqz/download). Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

There is [Devicon](https://github.com/devicons/devicon) a set of icons representing programming languages, designing, and development tools. You can use it as a font or directly copy/paste the SVG code into your project.